# PDO Exception: An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver for mysql

Tags: symfony, pdo, driver

I know it is frequently asked question. But I reviewed and read all of it. Unfortunately I could not find a correct answer for my problem. I am using symfony. I followed the instruction and tutorial on https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html. all steps went perfectly.  I run the following commands in terminal without any problem:

```
composer require symfony/orm-pack
composer require --dev symfony/maker-bundle
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
php bin/console make:entity
php bin/console make:migration
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
php bin/console make:controller ProductController
```

with the above commands I could create a database, ProductEntity, a table for Product
Till this point I suppose that the connection to my database runs perfectly.
Then in ProductController I used the Code on the symfony website:

```
// src/Controller/ProductController.php
namespace App\Controller;

// ...
use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/product", name="create_product")
     */
    public function createProduct(): Response
    {
        // you can fetch the EntityManager via $this->getDoctrine()
        // or you can add an argument to the action: createProduct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $product = new Product();
        $product->setName('Keyboard');
        $product->setPrice(1999);
        $product->setDescription('Ergonomic and stylish!');

        // tell Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Product (no queries yet)
        $entityManager->persist($product);

        // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
        $entityManager->flush();

        return new Response('Saved new product with id '.$product->getId());
    }
}
```

It gives Error: Driver not found like in the picture
I have checked database url in env, it works without problem (I created a database and product table through it). I checked phpinfo and pdo_mysql is enabled without problem.
I have tested database connection with fixature following the instruction here https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html and was successful without problem
Can you please help me?

[image: see the Picture of Error]

Comment: it seems to me like the driver is enabled in PHP CLI, but not in the web server PHP. which server are you using?

Comment: I use this command in terminal: symfony server:start

Comment: what is the output of `symfony php -m`? does it include pdo and pdo_mysql?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to guillaumesmo, I used symfony php -m. Here I saw the error unable to load pdo_mysql library. I remembered, that I have 2 PHP Versions installed on my system. 
I updated the PHP Version to PHP 7.4.1 and deleted the older versions. It works perfectly. I didn't understand why could I connect and update my database via Terminal and Fixature but not with EntityManagerInterface. Anyhow I works now

Comment: This was my issue. I could not find out any where on the internet that my issue was having multiple PHP versions. Thanks!